# How to execute a task when a set of users have completed a task? Can this be done using nodejs and mongodb?

Tags: node.js, event-handling, blockchain, smartcontracts

System will be creating a task for a set of users. When all reviewers have completed the task, a blockchain smart contract function needs to be invoked which can be done from the server side. But I am not sure how to schedule a task for a set of users and wait for them to finish it. How can I keep track of the tasks? Can this be done using nodejs and mongoDB?

Comment: Yes, that can be done. you put all tasks as new documents into a collection in mongodb.Once a user complete a task, you can query uncompleted tasks, and when there is non, you can call your smart contract.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest variant of Ethereum smart-contract bellow.
The process goes something like this:

1. "Main node" for each task creates a smart contract "Task" specifying the name of the task, its description (for example, URL or IPFS-manifest file with a description) and a list of viewers accounts.
2. The viewer on its node catches the TaskOpened event and analyzes the task
3. If the Viewer confirms the completion of the task, it transactionally calls method AcceptTask, if it prohibits it, it calls method RejectTask
4. If all Viewers confirm the completion of the task, then at the moment of the last confirmation event TaskConfirmed is generated, which catches the "Master node" and any viewers
5. If at least one of the Viewers prohibits the task execution, event TaskDeclined is generated immediately, which catches the "Master node" and any viewers

   pragma solidity >=0.5.2 <0.6.0;

   contract Task
   {
   address    Owner ;

   ```
    bytes32    Name ;
    string     Description ;
    bytes32    State ;

    uint256     AnswersWaitCnt ;

    struct Viewer
    {
      bytes32  reply ;
      string   remark ;
    }

    mapping (address => Viewer) ViewersState ;

    event TaskAssigned (address viewer, bytes32 name, string description) ;
    event TaskConfirmed(bytes32 name) ; 
    event TaskDeclined (bytes32 name, address viewers, string remark) ; 

    constructor(bytes32 name_, string memory description_, address[] memory viewers_) public

    { 
        uint256  i    ;

              Owner= tx.origin ;

               Name= name_ ;
        Description= description_  ;
     AnswersWaitCnt= viewers_.length ;

              State="New"  ;


          for(i=0 ; i<viewers_.length ; i++) 
          {
              ViewersState[ viewers_[i] ]=Viewer({  reply: "wait", 
                                                   remark: ""      }) ;

                   emit TaskAssigned(viewers_[i], Name, Description) ; 
          }
    }

    function GetState() public view returns (bytes32, bytes32, string memory retVal)
    {
       return(Name, State, Description) ;
    }

    function AcceptTask() public
    {
        if( ViewersState[ tx.origin ].reply== 0x00 )  return ;
        if( ViewersState[ tx.origin ].reply!="wait")  return ;

            ViewersState[ tx.origin ].reply="accept" ;

               AnswersWaitCnt-- ;

        if(AnswersWaitCnt==0)
        {
              State="Confirmed"  ;
          emit TaskConfirmed(Name) ;
        }
    }

    function RejectTask(string memory remark_) public
    {
        if( ViewersState[ tx.origin ].reply== 0x00 )  return ;
        if( ViewersState[ tx.origin ].reply!="wait")  return ;

            ViewersState[ tx.origin ].reply ="deny" ;
            ViewersState[ tx.origin ].remark= remark_ ;

              State="Declined" ;

          emit TaskDeclined(Name, tx.origin, remark_) ;
    }
   ```

   }